# Javascript - GUI programming

Tags: javascript, user-interface

When the selection of the dropdown does change, I would like to:

1) show some GUI blocking overlay via a div over the whole website

2) then process some code

3) then hide the overlay.

The problem is that when I write this logic in the eventlistener-function then onChange 2) would execute, then the GUI performs the updates of 1) and 3), because the GUI is only updating in Javascript when all functions are executed. That's not the correct order and not what I want.

So I thought I introduce a Webworker, but it turned out that the Webworker does exeactly nothing, the order is still wrong.

demo_workers.js:

```js
postMessage("show_overlay_runtime");
postMessage("do_stuff");
postMessage("hide_overlay_runtime");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #overlay {
                position: absolute;
                top:200px;
                left:0;
                background-color: #000;
                display:none;
                width:100%;
                height:200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <select id="my_dropdown">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            let my_dropdown = document.getElementById('my_dropdown');
            my_dropdown.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                dropdown_network_change_response();
            }, false);
            
            var workers = {};

            function dropdown_network_change_response() 
            {
                let worker_name = "worker1";
                startWorker(worker_name, "demo_workers.js");
                workers[worker_name].onmessage = function(event) {
                    if(event.data === "show_overlay_runtime") {
                        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "flex";
                    }
                    else if (event.data === "do_stuff") {
                        for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

                        }
                    }
                    else if (event.data === "hide_overlay_runtime") {
                        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
                    }
                    alert("test");
                };
            }

            function startWorker(worker_name, file) {
                if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
                    if(typeof(workers[worker_name]) == "undefined") {
                        workers[worker_name] = new Worker(file);
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
                }
            }

            function stopWorker(worker_name) { 
                workers[worker_name].terminate();
                workers[worker_name] = undefined;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So how can I achieve what I mentioned above in Javascript?

Comment: Look into the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: setTimeout is not what I want. I want hide when do_stuff is executed and not when a timer does elapse

Comment: Use it to *start* `do_stuff`, so the GUI gets a chance to show the overlay.

Comment: Can you please post the edited code? I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: I mean how can I perform a series of actions (after a user interaction with the GUI) but the first action should perform a GUI update before the 2nd action does start? I guess that is the question in one sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to give the GUI a chance to do its updating before certain code starts; for example:

```
function afterGUIupdate() {
    postMessage("do_stuff");
    postMessage("hide_overlay_runtime");
}
postMessage("show_overlay_runtime");
setTimeout( afterGUIupdate, 1 );
```

Technically, your code finishes after calling `setTimeout`, so the GUI can do its updating.  Then the timeout kicks in, executing the code you want to occur after that.

Comment: I do not even need the Worker right? What's then the purpose of a Worker, I mean isn't that the best scenario for having a Worker normally? I mean the Worker does exatcly nothing without using setTimout...

Comment: The setTimeout solution is not very clean. I have a css transition within show and hide and the show-transition should finish before hide is triggered. This is not possible with setTimout. It seems like Javascript has big issues with GUI programming. Is there any clean solution for this problem?

Comment: Call `setTimeout` when you've detected the end of the transition; *how* to do that has been answered elsewhere.